# Can't deploy Rails and Faye app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, chat, faye

I am making a chatting application using Ruby on Rails with Faye gem.

The app works on localhost after I inserted "localhost:9292/faye.js" in the index.html and I run the following script on command line:

```
rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production
ruby faye.rb
```

However, the app doesn't work on Heroku even if I changed the source url to "http://myappname.herokuapp.com/faye.js" and makes these errors.

```
http://myappname.herokuapp.com/faye.js 404 (Not Found)
ReferenceError: Faye is not defined
```

I've tried these commands but no luck so far.

```
heroku bundle exec rackup faye.ru -s thin
heroku bundle exec ruby faye.rb
```

It would be great if you could figure this out.

I appreciate for your help in advance!

---

I changed the url to "http://myappname.herokuapp.com:9292/faye.js"
and run the following commands on the commandline

```
heroku run bundle exec rackup faye.ru
heroku run bundle exec ruby faye.rb
```

Now I am getting this error

```
http://myappname.herokuapp.com:9292/faye.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

---

I tested the app with "foreman start" on localhost and everything worked.

However, it still does not work on Heroku.

Comment: Do you have a [procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) that executes these commands?

Comment: No, I don't. In my procfile, I put only this to use thin server -web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV.

Comment: I put the following codes in procfile and deployed it to Heroku. "web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
web: bundle exec rackup faye.ru
web: bundle exec ruby faye.rb."  Now the site itself doesn't work.

Comment: read up on procfiles with that article I linked to. It is how heroku manages processes, first get it working with foreman on your local machine and then if you transfer it to heroku and it still doesn't work then you know you've got a heroku problem.

Comment: Sorry I can't give a proper answer, if there's anything else, update your question and post another comment and I hope I'll be able to help then, good luck! :)

Comment: Very weird. I accidentally deployed my app to heroku when its faye url was still "localhost:9292" and then somehow it worked!

Comment: Oh well, if you managed to sort out your problem, write it up as a solution and post it as an answer to your question, it'll be handy in case anyone else has a similar issue. Glad it's sorted.

Comment: Oops. It worked because I was running the commands on the localhost so it still does not work on Heroku...

Comment: I am also with this problem, managed to solve?